# The home single phase differential switch cuts whatever I did

Tags: switches, differential, circuit-breaker

I have a 30 mA sensitivity differential switch which cuts each time I lift the power switch even if the circuit breakers for the sockets and the lighting are off (even if all the circuit breakers on the panel are off).

I know that the differential switch cuts off if there is a current leak, but all the circuit breakers which supply the sub-circuits of the house are cut previously, I have searched a lot to solve this problem but the differential switch remains tripped, I replaced the differential switch but the problem is still happening.

Any idea why this problem still happening?

[image]

Comment: Is there a ground wire bonded to the neutral wire near the entry to the building? Is the ground wire bonded to a grounding rod? What country are you in?

Comment: +1 for the diagram... but this might be a better fit for diy.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I am not using the ground wire at all (algeria)

Comment: Problem is that neutral is floating and leaking to ground from the "subcircuits". Ground the neutral wire right at the main switch. [The ground circuit is connected to earth, and neutral circuit is usually connected to ground.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_and_neutral). Before that, I would be curious how much it leaks, and what voltage the neutral is. Olden days (very long ago), grounding was poor enough that I could borrow :-) power through neutral to earth.

Comment: Disconnect both live & neutral from the *load* side of your differential/GFCI/RCD switch - dos it still trip? Probably not. Disconnect all the neutrals coming back from the sub-circuits and then reconnect the live and neutral back to the switch. Individually add the neutral and switch on the live breaker *one circuit at a time*. You'll soon find the circuit causing the trouble. Also make 100% sure that the neutral on the *line* side of the switch is always separated from the neutrals on the *load* side.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this should be migrated to DIY.SE

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting a trip even if all the breakers are off, then it suggests that there is an unexpected link between your neutrals and something else.

That could be someone else's live, someone else's neutral, or something that's earthed.

---

> I am not using the ground wire at all (algeria)

Why not?  It could save your life.

Answer (score 1):

So you replaced the differential, we'll assume the new one is functional (and probably the old one too).

First, test the breakers to make sure you don't have a broken one. With the main breaker off, all power off, use a multimeter in continuity test mode across each breaker. When the breaker is on, it should show a short circuit, and when the breaker is off, it should show an open circuit.

If all the breakers are working, then this means when they are off, the Live wire is disconnected. Look for a Live wire that would go from the output of the differential to something else without going through a breaker.

If you don't find any, and since on the picture the breakers are of the old style that doesn't also cut Neutral, this means the fault is probably a short between Neutral and chassis (Earth) in an appliance somewhere. This will also trip the differential, and the breakers won't do anything about it if they don't cut Neutral.

In order to find it, you will have to disconnect all the Neutrals. In this style of installation they should all be connected together via screw terminals, it looks like this, with or without the plastic case depending on age of installation:

[image]

So, unscrew all the Neutrals and pull them out, tuck them to make sure they don't touch anything (it's a good idea to tape them to something). They should not make contact with each other. When you switch power back on, any appliance that is turned on will create a low impedance between its Live and its Neutral as it tries to get some current, and this means when you turn power back on, **all the Neutrals will be live** if you turn on the individual breakers. So it is much safer to leave all the breakers in the off position, since that trips the differential anyway, you should be able to reproduce the problem with them off. Also make sure no-one is touching anything metallic or any appliance in the house, including sinks, faucets, showers, etc, because there is a faulty appliance somewhere that is leaking current, and that current is no longer going to Earth and tripping the differential.

So, with all breakers off, turn the power on, switch the differential to ON, it should not trip.

Turn power off, put one Neutral back in its terminal, screw it... turn power on... (Still with all breakers off)

Repeat until you find the Neutral that trips your differential. The problem is on this circuit.

Of course, make sure you follow adequate safety precautions.